# Hashicorp Terraform - Storing Azure Storage account access key in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-storage, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

Just as a disclaimer, I'm quite new to Terraform, and I'm trying to figure out how to store my Azure Storage Account Access Key in my Azure Key Vault. (Referenced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/terraform/terraform-backend)).

The specific command that is referenced is:

```
export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=$(az keyvault secret show --name terraform-backend-key --vault-name myKeyVault --query value -o tsv)
```

I get that the --vault value should be replaced with the name of my Key Vault, but what am I supposed to replace the --name value with?

And as importantly, in what file/config am I supposed to put the whole export ARM_ACCESS_KEY string?

Thanks so much, everyone!

Comment: Does the answer work to you? If it works you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To store the Terraform state in Azure Storage Account, the necessary resource is Storage account, but for you, you want to store your storage access key in the Azure Key Vault. So you need to create a new Key Vault or use the existing one.

You can use the CLI command to store your storage access key in your key vault like this:

```
az keyvault secret set --name secret_name --vault-name yourKeyvault_name --value yourStorageAccessKey
```

Then use the command you provide to export the environment variable **ARM_ACCESS_KEY**:

```
export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=$(az keyvault secret show --name secret_name --vault-name yourKeyvault_name --query value -o tsv)
```

Then you just need to follow the steps in the document that you have referred in your question.

**Update**

If you want to set the [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6) when you in Windows, you can do it like this:

```
$env:VAR_NAME='vaule'
```

In your issue, you could export the storage access key like this:

```
$env:ARM_ACCESS_KEY=(az keyvault secret show --name secret_name --vault-name yourKeyvault_name --query value -o tsv)
```

Change the secret_name and yourKeyvault_name into your resource. The result on my side:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! So I did input the secret name and key vault name, along with my storage access key, but when I run the command (the first one you referenced), I get an access denied message. I'm sure I'm using the correct storage access key. Any idea why this might be occurring?

Comment: Also, secondly, whenever I try to run the export command, it can't recognize the command. I'm assuming that I need to insert that line in a configuration somewhere? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Neal Well, there are two possible reasons for the permission. One is that you need the root permission to execute the command. The other one is you should log in the Az with the command `az login`. It's better if you provide the error details.

Comment: @Neal The export is a shell command in Linux, I think all the Linux Os will install it in default. But you'd better take a check.

Comment: I have actually used the az login command, and even selected the correct subscription. I've also authenticated using a Service Principal that I created, and that SP has the appropriate permissions. 

Regarding your other comment, I should have mentioned that I am running these commands from the command prompt in Windows 10. Is there any way to get that export command to run from this context?

Comment: @Neal I cannot see that you run the command in Windows 10 anywhere. But if you run it in Windows, you can set the environment variable like `$env:ARM_ACCESS_KEY=(az keyvault secret show --name secret_name --vault-name yourKeyvault_name --query value -o tsv)`.

Comment: I did try out the string you recommended, but I received the following message: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @Neal I add it in the answer and show the steps on my side. Take a look.

Comment: The post answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

`--name` is for keyvault secret's name.

Which file/config to put?

In Terraform the names of individual files are not significant and instead Terraform works with whole directories. The idea is to first execute this(state mechanism). I usually put it in the terraform.tf : these are the contents and `backend` section gets the key from env variable(as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage?tabs=azure-cli))

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.46.0"
    }
  }
    backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = "tfstate"
        storage_account_name = "<storage_account_name>"
        container_name       = "tfstate"
        key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    }

}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "state-demo-secure" {
  name     = "state-demo"
  location = "eastus"
}
```

Another option is to use [tfmake](https://pypi.org/project/tfmake/).
When using tfmake as a wrapper around terraform , setting the ARM_ACCESS_KEY  can be automated using it's configuration as follows:

$PROJECT/.tfmake/config

---

```
provider: azure
 
environment:
    - ARM_ACCESS_KEY = $(az keyvault secret show --name storage-account-key1 --vault-name kv-terraform-storage --query value -o tsv)
```

Using this configuration, the ARM_ACCESS_KEY  will become an environment variable just before actually executing any terraform  command.